# If $A_1 \subseteq B_1$ and $A_1 \cup A_2 \subseteq B_1 \cup B_2$ then $A_2$ is not necessarily a subset of $B_2$

Tags: general-topology

[image: Venn diagram illustrating]

If $A_1 \subseteq B_1$ and $A_1 \cup A_2 \subseteq B_1 \cup B_2$ then $A_2$ is not necessarily a subset of $B_2$ as illustrated by this Venn diagram.

I have tried to find an analytical example of such sets. But unfortunately, it is impossible (I think) to find such an example with sets in $\mathbb R$ (the euclidean metric space). In $\mathbb R^2 $ (the euclidean metric space) the intersections are a bit too tedious for me to handle. For example, I don't know how to write explicitly the intersection between $\{ y \mid |y|\leq 3 \}$ and $\{ y \mid |y-2| \leq 2 \}$

Maybe you guys would know an example of such sets.

PS: I apology for the colors, that do not express fully the sets. I tried to hatch the green and the blue to repair this lack of clarity.

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical" example?. Do you mean that you want to have explicit 2d plot of the Venn diagram? .

Comment: Or do you mean that you want your $A_{i},B_{i}$ to be open sets(i.e. sets in the Euclidean topology)? . In that case you can come up with millions of easy examples. For instance if $A_{1}=(0,1),A_{2}=(0,\frac{1}{2}), B_{1}=(0,2)$ and $B_{2}=(3,4)$

Comment: As an illustrative example, you can take $A_1=A_2=B_1$, and $B_2$ any other set not containing the first set (for example disjoint from it).

Comment: Your Diagram shows more effort than in most other Posts , I would not worry too much about it. It has enough clarity !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Example will work :

$ A_1 = \{ 1 , 2 , 3 \} $
$ B_1 = \{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 \} $
$ A_2 = \{ 3 , 6 , 9 \} $
$ B_2 = \{ 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 \} $

Given :
$ A_1 \subseteq B_1 $ : True
$ A_1 \cup A_2 \subset B_1 \cup B_2 $ : True

We can not claim :
$ A_2 \subseteq B_2 $ : not True (What the Post is wanting to know)

We can claim :
$ A_2 \subseteq B_1 \cup B_2 $ : True

The way to generate the Examples is :
Make sure there is some element in $A_2$ which is there in $B_1$ , but not there in $B_2$.
Here , $A_2$ has 3 ( & 6 ) which will occur in $B_1$ , but will not occur in $B_2$ , hence it will not make the subset.

Comment: They are fine as examples of sets in the discrete topology but not in the euclidean topology as is asked by the op.

Comment: I am not sure , but I think that it was a Suggestion , not a "Hard" requirement for OP , @Mr.GandalfSauron , OP wanted to "Convert" the given Diagram into Sets , though there are easier Examples !